# Jquery get params from json then send params to api

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json like this

```
{
  "latlng": [
    {
      "lat": "39.921",
      "lng": "116.392"
    },
    {
      "lat": "39.916",
      "lng": "116.415"
    }
 ]
}
```

then I got a api like "search?lat=&lng=&"

I want to use LAT/LNG params in the api

how can I do this?

Comment: if `obj` is that JSON thingy then to get the first lat you'll use `obj["latlng"]["lat"]`

Comment: @ShaiAharoni the API might be a JSONp. This means OP can use it on client side as wel..

Answer (score 1):

Parse the JSON, get one set of coordinates from the array, and build the URI with the coordinates. Example:

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
var coor = obj.latlng[0]; // get first item
var url = "search?lat=" + coor.lat + "&lng=" + coor.lng;
```

If you get the JSON using for example `$.get` with the right settings, it will automatically parse the JSON for you, so then the first step is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can deserialize json to jQuery object and can use the values as follows,

```
var data = $.parseJSON(latlng);

$.each(data,function(index,value){
    // Access values for eg: search?lat=value.lat&lng=&value.lng
});
```